# Can anyone give me an example of a function that has limit at only one point in R?

Tags: calculus, limits

What is the example of function that has only one limit in R?

Comment: Do you mean only one limit value (the straightforward meaning of the question) or a limit at only one place? 5xsum's answer satisfies both meanings.

Comment: I mean ,limit at only one placce

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}x & x\in \mathbb Q\\ 0& \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Comment: Also the asker can use $f(x) = \begin{cases}x & x\in \mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q\\ 0& \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$

Comment: Could you explain why ?

Comment: @user268336 I could, but I think this is a good exercise for you to try on your own.

Comment: Limit only exists at 0?

Comment: @user268336 Looks like it... Can you prove that's the case?

Comment: Yes I see now, Thank you